# How to have a form with a file field automatically submit on change with cross browser support

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, security

I am trying to have a form with a file field submit and upload the file as soon as the user selects the file. I have tried a couple of things, many of them work in some of the major browsers, but none of them work in all of them. I have so far tried 3 variations with javascript/jQuery scripts.

1st variation:

```
$('#fileField').on('change', function() {
    $('#form1').submit()
})
```

2nd variation:

```
$('#fileField').on('change', function() {
    $('#btn_form1_submit').click()
})
```

3rd variation:

```
<input type="file" id="fileField" name="fileUpload" onChange="this.form.submit()" />
```

All of these variations do cause the form to submit, and sometimes it even shows the progress of the file upload (depends on which browser), but then the file is never actually processed by the server side script. Everything works fine when I get rid of these scripts and manually press the 'upload' button.

Is there a way to do this with pure js? What about with incorporating anything else (flash etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Give the INPUT tag a `name` attribute.  That's why you're not seeing anything server-side.

Comment: In the running code there is a name attribute. I paraphrased on that line. Everything works perfectly when I add in a submit button and submit the form manually (form submits, file is received server side and is properly processed).

Comment: Would need to see the rest of the code setup, then, to help.  Never a good idea to "paraphrase" code by leaving out the important stuff when asking for help. ;)

Comment: Truth. With the name attribute included, it is no longer just paraphrased. The important part of the 3rd variation is with the onChange attribute.

Comment: Can you include the full JS and server-side code dumping the variables?  I don't see anything wrong with what you've provided.